# Why ELinq Skip/Take require OrderBy?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am picking-up here [a very old thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a15ba30-b16e-47bc-b23b-4f8a22234978/bug-in-elinq-skip-implementation?forum=adodotnetentityframework) but since the answer is "because this is by design" I would like to get a little more clarity.

It seams to me that this should be a rather provider specific issue - the SQL Server implementation of ROW_NUMBER() requires OVER with ORDER BY. In fact other SQL dialects (e.g. Vertica) allow ROW_NUMBER() with OVER() - notice the empty parentheses. I realize that the result is unpredictable (esp. in Vertica), and yet in some cases it might be OK.

Comment: What is ELinq? Is it this https://elinq.codeplex.com/?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq is the namespace where the Linq to Entities is implemented in Entity Framework.

Comment: It's internal implementation and even is not documented. It's usually just called LINQ to Entities, and that's it.

Comment: I understand this, but since the code is now open source and my question is mostly for the architects and developers of EF, I did not see a problem of referring to it.